# What is the amount of SSL on cloudflare? Is there any limit?

Tags: ssl, cloudflare

probably i just can't google correctly what I wanna know about. So, maybe someone of you might know this.
My question is: is there any limit of SSL amount on cloudflare? I mean, can i create over 9000 websites and still have a free SSL for every of them, or there's any limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the [Free Plan](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/plans/free/) and [Universal SSL certificates](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/edge-certificates/universal-ssl), I would recommend to familiarise with the [Cloudflare Terms of Use](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/website-terms/) and [Self-Serve Agreement](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/terms/) which provide useful information on what is allowed.

As far as I am aware, there isn't a limit "per-se" on the number of zones that can be added in an account ([see also here](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/limit-to-number-of-dns-zones-in-cloudflare-account/137011/6?u=vortexmind) as reference)